# How can I solve this Excel Formula Error?

Tags: excel, formula

[image: #Value Error]

I want to compute F1 score based on Recall and Precision using Excel. I typed this equation "=2*(B3*C3)/(B3+C3)" in the cell D3 and the #Value error occurred. I'm sure there were no texts or spaces in B3 and C3. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Probably need to `CLEAN` or `TRIM` B3 and/or C3. They're not true numbers.

Comment: Looks like those numbers are actually text.

Comment: Easy solution: format the text values as numbers.  More cumbersome and not recommended solution: wrap each text cell reference in `VALUE(B3)` within your formula.  "The Excel VALUE function converts text that appears in a recognized format (i.e. a number, date, or time format) into a numeric value."

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? I tried to format the cells as text, added spaces before and after the value and still cannot reproduce the issue...

Comment: @Marc FYI, formatting the text values as numbers will **NOT** change them from a text value to a numeric value.

Comment: There is likely a non-printing character in those cells which is causing them to be interpreted as text and not as a number.  Where did these values come from? What happens if you just type the values into the cells manually?